# Prove or disprove that $\overline{A}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have this exercise where $X$ is a topological Hausdorff space, and we let $A$ be an infinite subset of the topological space. We have that for every $a\in A$ there exists an open subset $U\subseteq X$ with $A\cap U =\{a\}$, then I have to prove or disprove that $\overline{A}$ is not compact. I am thinking That I have to prove this, by finding an open cover of $\overline{A}$ for which we have that there is no finite subcollection of this cover which covers $\overline{A}$, but I am confused about which open cover to look at.

Furthermore I have to tell what I can deduce for $A=\mathbb{Z}\subseteq X=\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard topology. Here I am thinking $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff. $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is infinite. And then I am thinking if I can show that for every $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists an open subset  $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$  with $\mathbb{Z}\cap U =\{a\}$ (which I am confused about how to do), then I'll have that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{Z}$ is not compact.

Comment: "Prove or disprove that $\bar A$ is not compact" is an unnecessary double negative (unless it's not the case that you aren't using intuitionistic logic).

Answer (score 2):

The family of open sets $U_a$ such that $U\cap A=\{a\}$ seems a nice cover.

For the second part, take $U_n=(n-h, n+h)$ for some $0<h<1$

Comment: but how can I be sure that $\{U_a\cap A\}_{a\in A}$ is an open cover? and isn't this a cover for A. How do I show that this is a cover for $\overline{A}$. Then I'd have to show that $\overline{A}\subseteq \bigcup_{a\in A} U_a\cap A$, and how would I do that?

Comment: $\bar A=A$ because $A$ has no accumulation points. And $\bigcup_{a\in A}(U_a\cap A)=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}=A$.

Comment: How do we know that A has no accumulation points? And then I still have to check if $U_a \cap A$ is open. We know that $U_a$ is open, but how do we know that A is open as well? And the reason why  $\{U_a\cap A\}_{a\in A}$ doesn't contain a finite subcover is that because $\{U_a\cap A\}_{a\in A}$ is infinite?

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\{\frac1n\mid n=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$ (in $\Bbb R$, usual topology), then $\overline{A}=A \cup \{0\}$ *is* compact. Your example $A=\Bbb Z$ is one where $\overline{A}=A$ is not. So both are possible.

Comment: So $\overline{A}$ can be both compact and not compact?

Comment: @Sara indeed. You cannot prove one or the other.